# Odoo send mail via API from Purchase Order : record does not exist

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

Running odoo on vps.

I Try to send mail from validated purchase order using :

```
sendMail = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'purchase.order', 'action_rfq_send',[orderId],{'context' : {'send_rfq': False}})

models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mail.compose.message', 'action_send_mail',[[sendMail['context']['default_template_id']]])
```

Mailing is configured and works when triggered manually

I get these outputs: [image: error messages]

First block is a print of the output of the sendMail method

Second block is the output of the xmlrpc action_send_mail that comes after.

I must be missing a parameter in either the sendMail or the action_send_mail but I couldn't find which. I have also tried replacing default_template_id by view_id as such:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mail.compose.message', 'action_send_mail',[[sendMail['context']['view_id']]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the mail wizard by xml-rpc is possible, but i wouldn't use it.

But the error is the following. You're trying to use `action_send_mail` of the mail wizard, which needs the currents wizard id. But you're giving `[sendMail['context']['view_id']]` (or `default_template_id`) which is not a wizards ID.

The method `action_send_mail` of `purchase.order` is returning an action in form of a dictionary. The only key/value pair in an odoo window action dictionary holding an actual ID of the actions underlying model is `res_id` and in this case, there is never one in it. That's because Odoo made that method for the browser client...

So what can you do instead? First you should look into `action_send_mail` to get what's done there and what values you could use. There are a lot of things for the browser and the wizard. But for xml-rpc only 2 things are really necessary: the order ID and the mail template ID.

You already have the order id, in your example code `orderId`. For Odoo 15 there are two mail templates used by the wizard. Let's stick to the one with xml id `purchase.email_template_edi_purchase`, which will be used in my example code later on.

You now can use both IDs to send the mail by using the features of Odoo's mail templates.

That following code is for Odoo 15 and probably not working in older versions.

```py
# first get mail template id (either by xml id or you could hardcode it, but that's ugly)
mail_template_xml_id = "purchase.email_template_edi_purchase"
module, xml_id_name = mail_template_xml_id.split(".")
template_model, template_id = models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password, 'ir.model.data',
    'check_object_reference',
    [module, xml_id_name])
# send the mail by template
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, template_model,
    'send_mail',
    [template_id, orderId])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips !

I will complete this answer: The above code creates the mail but doesn't actually send it (running on Odoo 16), i managed to send the mail by adding the following bit :

```
mailId = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, template_model, 'send_mail', [template_id, orderId]) 
models.execute_kw(db,uid,password, 'mail.mail', 'send', [mailId] )
```